# cannot mount usb partition - unknown file system exfat

Tags: usb-drive, exfat

I have a USB stick with important info that would not show up in Windows. I tried the Disk Management Utility, and the partition with the data shows up as "healthy", but no drive letter, and right-click menu options all grayed out (except 'delete'). I used another laptop, I used a Macbook, all to no avail.

On Ubuntu, it also would not show up. I tried manual mounting, which did not work, and on parted it the "File system" column is empty.

Using fdisk -l it shows as HPFS/NTFS/exFAT.

???

Answer (score 1):

I thought to remove my question, but since it took me a while to find the answer, others may benefit:

sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils

Now I could mount it with exfat specified as file system (and anyway now Ubuntu also automatically mounted it).

Answer (score 0):

uanble to mount exfat file system then needs to follow below steps
Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T shortcut in Ubuntu).

sudo add-apt-repository universe

sudo apt update

sudo apt install exfat-fuse exfat-utils